# Rails Locals - Passing Connected Model Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My model structure is pretty solid. I have MarketingDeliverySystem has_many MarketingSections. MarketingSections has_many MarketingVideos.

I have another segment: GroupDevelopment has_many GroupSections. GroupSections has_many GroupVideos.

I'm trying to use a partial to pass the variables, thus DRYing it all up.

I have the following that I'm trying to pass to the partial:

```
= render partial: '/sales_presentations/sales_presentation',
                    locals: { marketing_delivery_system: @marketing_delivery_system,
                              first_video: first_marketing_video(@marketing_delivery_system),
                              sales_presentation: @marketing_delivery_system}
```

Then in the partial I have the following:

```
.rounded-box-header.blue-bg #{sales_presentation.title}   
 ul
  - sales_presentation.sections.ordered.each_with_index do |section, index|
   - list_class = 'section show'
   - list_class = 'section hide' if index != 0
     li
      = link_to section.title, '#', class: 'section', data: { id: section.id }
              ul class="#{list_class}" data-section-id="#{section.id}"
                - section.videos.ordered.each do |video|
                  li.video
                    = link_to video.title, '#',
                                           class: 'video video-link',
                                           data: { video: video.youtube_link,
                                                   sales_presentation: sales_presentation.title.parameterize }
      .seven.columns
        .row
          div id="#{sales_presentation.title.parameterize}-container"
            video {
              id="#{sales_presentation.title.parameterize}-video-player"
              class="video-js vjs-default-skin videos"
              height=400
              poster=""
              controls preload='none'
              data-default-url="#{first_video(sales_presentation)&.youtube_link}"
```

I previously had issues with sales_presentation.title at the top until I updated the locals.

My question/issue is how do I pass in through the locals to use for sales_presentation.sections instead to use @marketing_delivery_system.marketing.sections?

I thought I could just put that in through locals:
sales_presentation.sections: @marketing_delivery_system.marketing_sections but I end up with a massive syntax error.

I've also tried creating a partial view for these two and then changed sales_presentation throughout the view to mod. Then changed mod.sections to mod_section and setting that in the locals to mod_section: @marketing_delivery_system.marketing_section. The problem then gets into that I end up needing to hit video later in the iteration. So then that has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand the meaning of `locals` in partials.

Says we have

```
<%= render partial: 'image', locals: {size: @image.size, extension: @image.extension} %>
```

It means that in `image` partial now we can use local variable `size` and `extension` (keys) as `@image.size` and `@image.extension` (values).

Put in `locals: {}` all local variables you want.

So you can't write in locals `sales_presentation.sections: @marketing_delivery_system.marketing.sections`

But you can `sales_presentation_sections:  @marketing_delivery_system.marketing.section`

Also you have problem with this code:

> ```
> locals: { marketing_delivery_system: @marketing_delivery_system,
>           first_video: first_marketing_video(@marketing_delivery_system),
>           sales_presentation: @marketing_delivery_system }
> ```

`marketing_delivery_system` and `sales_presentation` will be with the same value.